# AIR: How to set NativeWindow type to Utility

Tags: air, flex4, nativewindow

The nativeWindow supports systemChrome (standard,none) and transparent (false,true); These options are in the Adobe AIR Application Descriptor File (xml)

```
    <!-- The type of system chrome to use (either "standard" or "none"). Optional. Default standard. -->
    <!-- <systemChrome></systemChrome> -->

    <!-- Whether the window is transparent. Only applicable when systemChrome is none. Optional. Default false. -->
    <!-- <transparent></transparent> -->
```

But I can't find the option to set the window type (utility,normal,lightweight) as seen on the TourDeFlex under Air Applications -> AIR APIs and Techniques -> Native Windows.

From the application can be accessed just as a read-only property.

Where's the right place to set this property?

A good example of usage could be: minitask.org

Thanks!

Edit: The window should start in the UTILITY mode

Answer (score 1):

you have to set the [NativeWindowType](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindowType.html) of your window via [NativeWindowInitOptions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindowInitOptions.html)'s `type` property when you instantiate a window.

more here:  [AIR Window Basics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e09.html)

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to do this with a main application window.  A trick you could use is:

```
function MainConstructor() {

    var opt:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
    opt.type = NativeWindowType.UTILITY;

    var window:NativeWindow = new NativeWindow(opt);
    window.activate();
    window.stage.addChild(new PreviousMainConstructor());

    stage.nativeWindow.close();
}
```

this just opens a new utility window, and closes the main application window

Answer (score -1):

this.type = NativeWindowType.UTILITY;